# Is there something like "+=" in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to redefine a numerical attribute in SASS by increment or decrement? Consider something like this:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 10px;
}

h1.important {
    font-size: += 10px;
}
```

I know that I can work around that by defining a variable. Is it possible to do this without?

Comment: Not sure about SAS, but reckon this could be done in jQuery

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. But as SASS compiles to normal CSS, the SASS solution would work without JS enabled.

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if the `+=` works, but you could use a base variable and then add on to it in another class.

```
$baseFontSize: 10px

h1
  font-size: $baseFontSize


.border 
  font-size: $baseFontSize + 10px
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. The syntax proposed by the OP is very ambiguous... How is the parser supposed to know what to add 10px to?

Comment: The syntax isn't perfect, but there is no reason a parser can't work out that 10px is added to the current value of font-size. Statements like this are common in many languages.